# Locating a child of a child in Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to locate two input fields on an unordered menu list, but Selenium is unable to find them. So far I've attempted to locate them by xpath and class name with an ordinal identifier

```
("//input[@class=x-form-text x-form-field][4]")
```

but it either doesn't locate the element or it says it is improperly formatted.  The only success I've had is if I use the id, but the number on the end changes every time the page loads.

Is there any way to have it locate the menu list, then the list item, and then the input field?  I am totally stumped.

Notes about the menu list:  It changes size based on resolution and if it becomes much smaller a down arrow icon will appear and the fields towards the bottom of the list will disappear unless that down button is selected.

Here's an example of the html:

```
<ul id="ext-gen406" class="x-menu-list">
    <li id="ext-comp-1237" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1238" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1239" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1240" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1241" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1242" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1207" class="list-item sep-li">
    <li id="ext-comp-1243" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1244" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1208" class="list-item sep-li">
    <li id="ext-comp-1245" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1246" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1247" class="list-item ">
        <div class='xtb-text'>Text Field Label</div>
    <li id="ext-comp-1248" class="list-item ">
        <div id="ext-gen424" class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap">
            <input id="ext-comp-1248" class="x-form-text x-form-field"name="ext-comp-1248" 
        </div>
    <li id="ext-comp-1249" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1250" class="list-item ">
        <div class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap" id="ext-gen426">
             <input id="ext-comp-1250" name="ext-comp-1250" class="x-form-text x-form-field" 
         </div>        
    <li id="ext-comp-1251" class="list-item ">
    <li id="ext-comp-1252" class="list-item ">
</ul>
```

Comment: You should include the value of the class in single quotes like this: ("//input[@class='x-form-text x-form-field'][4]")

Comment: I just tried it in single quotes and still receive this error message: FAILED-EXCEPTION, Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@class='x-form-text x-form-field'][4]

Comment: @tinneko - Your question does not have enough information. Can you have more than two input fields on the page ? If yes, then how do you distinguish between the two inputs you want and the ones you don't want ?

Comment: There's actually 12 input fields in just that menu list, but the two I listed the details for are the ones I'm trying to locate.  The only thing that is unique between them is the ID and that number on the end changes every time the page loads, so it isn't reliable to use.  If I had another way to distinguish them then I wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: The two input fields that I'm trying to locate are the 9th and 10th input fields in this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so... I finally figured it out!

Here is what worked for me:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li/div[contains(text(), 'Text labeling input field')]/../following-sibling::li/div/input")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cssSelector to solve the issue,

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.x-menu-list input.x-form-field:nth-child(1)")  //first input box
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.x-menu-list input.x-form-field:nth-child(2)")  //second input box
```

Comment: Please comment the reason for down voting.

Comment: I would prefer your approach Sundharsan .  If you have multiple ul with the same x-menu-list class, then I would update this path with the wrapping element (typically a div).  the OP didn't provide enough information to be able to make this any more flexible...e.g. do they need to associate the input fields with a specific list item.

Comment: I tried this method and for some reason it only locates the first input field.  It doesn't locate any of the other input fields in the list.  (There are 12).  Can someone provide more information on how to use nth children?  Maybe this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried this method and for some reason it only locates the first input field. It doesn't locate any of the other input fields in the list. (There are 12). Can someone provide more information on how to use nth children?

In this case you should try using `find_elements` to find all `input` elements and perform certain action on particular element using index below :-

```
all_inputs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.x-menu-list > li.list-item input.x-form-text")
```

> The two input fields that I'm trying to locate are the 9th and 10th input fields in this list.

```
#now use index to get desire input element 
if len(all_inputs) >= 10:
  desire_input_9 = all_inputs[8]
  desire_input_10 = all_inputs[9]
```